# Getting detail with the highest priority using Joins/subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I hope you can help me with this problem: I have three tables, similar to this:

```
ORDER
Order_ID | Order_Date
=====================
       1 | 01/01/2001
       2 | 02/01/2001
       3 | 03/01/2001
       4 | 04/01/2001
       5 | 05/01/2001

ORDER_DETAIL
Order_Detail_ID | Order_ID | Status_ID
======================================
              1 |        1 |         1
              2 |        1 |         1
              3 |        1 |         2
              4 |        2 |         2
              5 |        2 |         3
              6 |        3 |         3
              7 |        3 |         3
STATUS
Status_ID | Status_Name | Status_Priority
=========================================
        1 | PENDING     |              3
        2 | COMPLETED   |              2
        3 | CANCELLED   |              1
```

Now, as I suppose it shows, each row in the ORDER_DETAIL table is related to the ORDER table using Order_ID, and it also has a status indicated by the Status_ID. Also, the STATUS table has a Status_Priority column. What I need to do is show each order, along with, among other columns, the status with highest priority among the order details each order has, like this:

```
Order_ID | Order_Date | Status_Name
===================================
       1 | 01/01/2001 | PENDING
       2 | 02/01/2001 | COMPLETED
       3 | 03/01/2001 | CANCELLED
       4 | 04/01/2001 |
       5 | 05/01/2001 |
```

In this case, for example, since Order_ID 1 has at least 1 Order_Detail_ID with the PENDING status, which has the highest priority among the details it has, that's the one that appears. I tried using a JOIN with a subquery, based on a similar code I have, but I can't seem to adapt it to this case. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Select columns, join tables by order_id, order by Status_Priority

Comment: I'm sorry,  but, isn't that answer a little vague? If I do only that I'll show one row per Order for each Order_Detail, and I want to show just one row per Order, and one Status_Name (the one among the Order's Order_Details with the hightest priority).